# How to automate ktutil to immediately list keytab entries?

Tags: shell, kerberos

I use MIT `ktutil` a lot on Linux and I am fed up using the following sequence, even if command shortcuts and file name completion are here to help:

```
ktutil
rkt my.keytab
l
```

Isn't there a way to get the same result in a "one-line" way from the shell? Either with an alias, a function, or just with another tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use `klist` instead to list the contents of keytab files out instead of `ktutil`.

#### Example #1 - klist

```
$ klist -kt /etc/somedir/conf/some.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/somedir/conf/some.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   5 08/25/15 11:18:35 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   5 08/25/15 11:18:35 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   5 08/25/15 11:18:35 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   7 08/25/15 11:18:35 app/host2.dom.local@TD.COM
...
```

#### Example #2 - process substitution

You can also use a redirect to `ktutil`'s STDIN like so:

```
$ ktutil < <(echo -e "rkt /etc/somedir/conf/some.keytab\nlist")
ktutil:  rkt /etc/somedir/conf/some.keytab
ktutil:  list
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    5 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   2    5 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   3    5 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
   4    7 app/host1.dom.local@TD.COM
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with a shell function, after guessing `ktutil` may accept commands from stdin:

```
rkt() { echo -e "read_kt $1\nlist\nquit" | ktutil | grep -v "^ktutil:"; }
```

And invoke with `rkt my.keytab`

Works as far as file name contains no space.

Answer (score 0):

This can help to merge 2 keytab, using standad input to use in shell script

```
ktutil < <(echo -e "rkt/var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab.server.keytab1\n
rkt /var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab.server.keytab1\n
wkt /var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab\n
quit")
ktutil:  rkt /var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab.server.keytab1
ktutil:  rkt /var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab.server.keytab1
ktutil:  wkt /var/tmp/keytab/merge/krb5.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers provide a way to run a series of ktutil commands and then exit.

It's more difficult to do a series of commands and then get an interactive session, with full line editing capabilities.

You can achieve this with a script for the `expect` program, which should be available to install from your distro.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f
spawn ktutil
send "read_kt [lrange $argv 0 1]\nl\n"
set CTRLZ \032
interact {
 -reset $CTRLZ {exec kill -STOP [pid]}
 \003 exit
}
```

Save as `myktutil` somewhere in your `PATH` and make it executable with `chmod +x`

Then you can do, for example:

`$ myktutil foo.keytab`

This will read in the keytab file `foo.keytab`, list the keys and then drop you into the interactive command at that point.

Extending the script to do non-trivial things will require familiarization with `expect` and the Tcl language.